# How to access updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fairly simple function that helps me browse through a set of pictures. Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" id="front" />

    <div id="#previous" class="buttons"></div>

    <div id="#next" class="buttons"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the function:

```
counter = 1;

$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function (e) {
  if (counter < 1 || counter > 20) {
    return false;
  }

  var id = e.target.id;
  if (id == "next" && counter < 20) {
    counter++;
  } else if (id == "previous" && counter > 1) {
    counter--;
  }
  getImage();
});

getImage = function () {
  document.getElementById("front").src = "Images/Image" + counter + ".jpg";
}
```

This works as expected and you can browse through a set of 20 images in this case. I have 2 arrows on both sides, one of the id of 'previous' and the other with the id of 'next'.

On my css I have a rule that fades in the arrows if you hover over the images:

```
#container #imagewrap:hover .buttons {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

What I am trying to do is that if the image is the very first image, the "previous" arrow does not show, and if the image is the very last image, the "next" arrow doesn't show.

so, something like that:

```
if (counter == 1) {
  $('previous').hide();
} else if (counter == 20) {
  $('next').hide();
}
```

This wasn't working. I then started to try to see if I could do it using the image source, so doing something like that:

```
var source = $('#front').attr('src');

alert(source);
```

But that doesn't work either as the source doesn't get updated outside of the function. I am a beginner as you can tell, so I am still struggling with scope etc... what is the best way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: So you have a `<previous>` and `<next>` element? And do you realize that `=` is for assignment?

Comment: hi, sorry this is just a typo here

Comment: But you did not fix the selectors.... You are selecting elements, not ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `#` in the selector. Try the following.

```
if (counter == 1) {
   $('#previous').hide();
   $('#next').show();
}
else if (counter == 20) {
   $('#next').hide();
   $('#previous').show();
}
```